# MySQL - select date range with overnight hours for each date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, mysqli

I have table that contains datetime, when selecting I would like to specify the date range as well as time range (overnight counted as previous day).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
id integer NOT NULL,
date datetime NOT NULL,
status integer NOT NULL,
x integer NOT NULL
);

insert into some_table(id, date, status, x)
values
(1, '2017-11-16 11:05:00', 1, 15),
(2, '2017-11-16 14:33:00', 1, 2),
(3, '2017-11-16 18:02:00', 1, 57),
(4, '2017-11-16 18:29:00', 1, 41),
(5, '2017-11-16 22:05:00', 1, 3),
(6, '2017-11-17 01:47:00', 1, 105),
(8, '2017-11-17 03:55:00', 1, 41),
(9, '2017-11-17 07:07:00', 1, 77),
(10, '2017-11-17 11:25:00', 1, 52),
(11, '2017-11-17 18:12:00', 1, 1),
(12, '2017-11-17 20:51:00', 1, 58)
```

currently I'm using 'interval' for time range from (YYYY-mm-dd 03:50:00) to (YYYY-mm-dd 03:50:00)*next day.

but it doesn't work as expected!

```
select  
  sum(x) AS total_x , 
  str_to_date(date + INTERVAL '03:50' HOUR_MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d') datex
from    some_table
WHERE
date between '2017-11-14' and '2017-11-18'
group by datex
```

Above results are:

```
 total_x  |    datex
 ------------------------
 115      |   2017-11-16
 279      |   2017-11-17
 58       |   2017-11-18
```

what I want to achieve:

```
 total_x  |    datex
 ------------------------
 223      |   2017-11-16
 229      |   2017-11-17
```

To find the above code:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e320f9/37

Comment: between '2017-11-14' and DATE_ADD('2017-11-18', INTERVAL 1 DAY). will this work ?

Comment: @Deep this wont group results by day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   select sum(x),aa.date from (
     select date(subtime(date,'0 3:50:0.0')) as date,x from some_table) aa 
     group by aa.date
```

Comment: @Erik .. krishna aryal has forgotten the `WHERE date between '2017-11-14' and '2017-11-18'` part

Comment: @krishna-aryal what if I want to make the range between 22:00 to 03:50 + one day? with keeping ` WHERE date between '2017-11-14' and '2017-11-18' `

Comment: try adding the where filter in the outer query not in the inner one

Answer (score 0):

```
   select
       sum(x) AS total_x
     , str_to_date(date - INTERVAL '03:50' HOUR_MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d') datex
   from some_table
   WHERE date between '2017-11-14' and '2017-11-18'
   group by datex
```

you should change `'+'` to `'-'`